# Skinning Halo scroll bar in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, scrollbar, flex-spark, halo

I have the Spark scroll bar in my application skinned the way I want where I use `s|VScrollBar` and then set `skinClass: ClassReference(my skin class)` in my CSS file. For my Halo scroll bar I have the skins set for each element of the scroll bar (arrows, thumb, track, etc.) but I want to have one central class like with the Spark scroll bar. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not in the same way as you can in Spark.  Spark was made for easy skinning which is the great thing about Flex 4, but Flex 3 did things very differently.

What you can do is extend the Flex 3 scrollbar into a custom class that sets all those elements in it.  Then within that project, just reference that custom class.  Sadly, that's all that can be done.

Comment: thats a shame... i just wanted to have a way of globally adding a hand cursor to the scroll bar for all halo components. oh well, thanks anyway